# Unify the `http-status-codes-nnn` tags under `http-status-codes`

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-synonym-request

I just asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/611464/ie7-persistently-displays-friendly-error-message-instead-of-http-error-code), which I wanted to tag with [http-status-codes](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/http-status-codes). However, no such tag exists, and I don't have enough rep to create the tag. I think the tag would nicely unify the existing [http-status-code-404](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-404) and [http-status-code-500](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-500) tags as synonyms.

Comment: Agreed. Added the tag for you. We'll see if it survives...